# AWS SAM building Layers locally with `--use-container` flag?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sam-cli

I'm using the sam cli to build and deploy AWS Lambdas:

> The sam build command iterates through the functions in your
> application, looks for a manifest file (such as requirements.txt) that
> contains the dependencies, and automatically creates deployment
> artifacts that you can deploy to Lambda using the sam package and sam
> deploy commands.

What's cool is that i can use the option flag `--use-container` to build functions that have natively compiled dependencies inside an AWS Lambda-like Docker container.

**What about AWS Lambda layers?**

I have a function:

```
  CreateImagesLambdaFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      Runtime: python3.7
      Handler: lambda_function.create
      CodeUri: ./functions/image_handler/
      ...
      Layers: 
        - !Ref LayerPillow
```

that uses a layer with natively compiled dependencies (thus must be installed on linux):

```
  LayerPillow:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::LayerVersion
    Properties:
      ...
      ContentUri: ./functions/layer_pillow/
```

I can get around this by just install the dependencies using the `amazonlinux:latest` docker image and copying to my repository, but was curious if SAM supported this functionality